# Are member functions of std::wstring_convert thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

We're using a

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
```

in a logger of ours that gets a UTF-16 string from a legacy component and converts it to UTF-8 that we write to the log. The converter gets instantiated on each conversion, upon which we do

```
auto utf8string = converter.to_bytes(utf16string);
```

This is done in a pretty intensive and multi-threaded part of our code and I'd like to re-use one instance of the converter, but seing that `std::wstring_convert` exposes a "state", I'm worried that `to_bytes` is not thread safe and any gains we could get by reusing the same instance would be lost by the excessive locking that would then be needed (in which case I wouldn't share the instance anyway).

So, is `std::wstring_convert<>::to_bytes` thread safe?

**EDIT:** A clarification on what I'm really asking: Given one instance of `std::wstring_convert<>`, if 2 or more threads concurrently call `to_bytes` on that instance with different arguments, is `to_bytes` then guaranteed to behave well?

Comment: @LucDanton: I think it's "allowed" to jot down a 2-line abstract of the important part ("const means thread safe") as an answer and add the link for the rest - then I can accept your answer.

Comment: A clarification to the above comment - the "const means thread safe" should be changed to "const means thread safe and to_bytes is not const, meaning it might change instance state"

Comment: @LucDanton: duh! thanks for noticing - changed it. Of course it's `to_bytes` (facepalm)

Comment: Even if it's not safe to use a single instance, you may be able to get some time-savings using one instance per thread, via `thread_local`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `std::wstring_convert` is part of the Standard Library, it follows [certain rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11/14127380) when it comes to handling an object of such type from different threads.

In particular, because both `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` overloads are non-`const`, it is not possible to use those members on any one particular object from different threads without synchronization. This makes sense, as codecvt conversions typically make use of a `state_type` object. Using it without synchronization would lead to disaster.