# Error: "cannot bind packed field" while inserting data into std::map using insert function

Tags: c++, gcc-extensions

Can somebody tell me the difference between `#pragma pack(push,1)` and `__attribute__((packed))`? I am getting a compilation error if I use second type of struct packing which says

> ```
> cannot bind packed field ‘ABC.abc::a’ to ‘unsigned int&’
> ```

But if I use first type of struct packing then there is no compilation error.

This is my sample code:

```
//DataStructure.h

#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_H_
#define DATASTRUCTURE_H_

struct abc
{
    unsigned int a;
    float b;
}__attribute__((packed));

#endif /* DATASTRUCTURE_H_ */



//Main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include "DataStructure.h"


int main()
{
    struct abc ABC;
    ABC.a=3;
    ABC.b=4.6f;

    std::map<unsigned int,struct abc> Mapp;
    Mapp.insert(std::make_pair(ABC.a,ABC));
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you on, and what is the compiler error you're getting?  Please edit the original question with that information.

Comment: I am using GCC compiler "gcc version 4.8.5 20150623". And this is the error I'm getting " cannot bind packed field ‘ABC.abc::a’ to ‘unsigned int&’ Mapp.insert(std::make_pair(ABC.a,ABC)); "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from:

```
std::make_pair(ABC.a,ABC);
```

Since C++11, [`make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) is defined as:

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

so giving it `ABC.a` as first argument is trying to **bind an lvalue reference to a bitfield** (what a packed struct is basically), [which is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608976/5470596).

To solve that, you must create a *fresh* unsigned int and call `make_pair` with it:

```
unsigned int a = ABC.a;
Mapp.insert(std::make_pair(a,ABC));
```

Comment: but why it is not giving an error if I use the first type of struct packing

Comment: @Harry I can't tell, `#pragma`s are implementation-specified.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a copy by hand. You can use the unary plus operator to force evaluation, which will promote `ABC.a` to an integer value:

```
Mapp.insert(std::make_pair(+ABC.a, ABC));
```

Comment: And increase the wtf/line kpi of your codebase...