# How c++ compiler guarantees thread safety of constant member variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, constants

C++ 11x standard changed semantic of "const" keyword.
Now it means real thread safety.
As far as I understand const member variable is equal to java final field.

I want to check that on CPU icore 7 G++ 4.7.1.

I compiled following code with as -std=c++0x -pthread -DCONST and without. Both executable are identical. Assembler versions don't have *fence instructions.
I expected to see *fence at the end of the constructor.

```
class Big {
public:
#ifdef CONST
  const
#endif
  long a;
  Big(long a) : a(a) {
  }
  void check()
 #ifdef CONST
  const 
 #endif
  {
    assert(a == 123L);
  }
};

int main() {
  Big b(123L);
  thread t([b] () { b.check(); });
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. It is up to you to make sure that something labeled `const` is safe when called from many threads.

Comment: There's no such thing like race conditions on accessing constant values!

Comment: Race conditions apply to read/write scenarios. Since `const` variables are read only by definition (or should be), there is no problem in accessing it simultaneously by multiple threads. Race condition could happen on initialisation. However, it's always a programmer's task to make sure this does not happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: @W.B. In C++, `const` access can also result in state change of `mutable` data members. Which is what I was what I had in mind when I posted my first comment.

Comment: CPU doesn't know whether a memory cell const or not. What if memory of B was reclaimed and reused and some CPU core will see the old value from cache. That left after object existed before B?

Comment: C++11 didn't change the meaning of `const`. It provides an additional guarantee about `const` members *within the standard library* being thread-safe. It does not mean "anything marked `const` in user code must be (or will be) thread-safe" (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11/14127380#14127380))

Comment: @W.B. I don't have any questions. This is all clear to me :-)

Comment: Here I meant thread safety is if a thread sees this of the complete object then it also sees right value of member a.

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov How could it see the wrong value in any scenario? Nothing is writing to `a` after initialization.

Comment: Initialization is just a language abstraction. CPU see a write at address of a. What protect from the situation: another thread on another core change the same address before and new object is passed to that thread.

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov: how exactly are not completely constructed objects passed to other threads (when not using insane constructs)?

Comment: You would have to work hard to engineer such a situation. In your example, the object is created in one thread, and the next thread only reads from it. If you wanted to write, the compiler would complain that you are writing to something marked as `const`. If you marked the data member `mutable`, then the thread would be able to perform a write to a "const" object.

Comment: I believe you may be referring to the "You dont know __ and __" talk by Herb Sutter. If so, he doesn't say that const *makes* something thread safe. He says that accessing the standard library classes *only* through const members is guaranteed to be thread safe and that because of an accidental (and lucky) combination of rules, your own classes must do that too (which luckily is normally the case by default since const implies no writes). You are effectively required to synchronize mutables to maintain this invariant. const *only* access is normally safe because races are caused by writes.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a general Computer Science question than a code question exactly, but that's fine, interesting even.

Let's establish some points, and if you have any issue with these points or my subsequent reasoning, then let me know.  Just to be clear, I use the word **observe** to kind of mean "read", and **modify** to kind of mean "write".  This is not a formal proof.

1. Any number of threads may **observe** an object concurrently without incurring a race condition, as long as no thread concurrently **modifies** that object.
2. A `const` object is **modified** during **initialization**, and not otherwise be **modified** during the lifetime of that object (except for destruction I suppose).
3. **Initialization** happens once during the lifetime of an object, in exactly one thread, before that object can be otherwise **modified** or **observed** (you technically can access an uninitialized object, but if you manage to pull that off a lot of things are broken regardless of thread-safety).

#2 and #3 guarantee that **a const member can not be concurrently modified and observed**, which is thread safe by rule #1.

Now... `mutable` changes things and once you start making `mutable` members, the onus is upon the class writer to make sure `const` methods using `mutable` members are handled in a thread-safe manner.

So, the compiler does not guarantee thread safety... but *logic* does guarantee thread safety.  As long as an object is `const`, all of its `mutable` members are handled in a thread-safe manner, and all of that object's `const` members observe these rules, you have a guarantee of thread safety.

The C++11 change as I understand is that where `std::` objects did not previously guarantee well-behaved thread-safe const members, we now have that guarantee.

The video [Herb Sutter - You don't know [blank] and [blank]](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) is as far as I can tell the source for the claim that C++11 guarantees that const == thread-safe, and explains the claim well.

Comment: wrt. the first half of your post, it's not just mutable causing problems. It's also something as simple as pointers. Say you have a const object containing a pointer. Sure, because the object is const, so is the pointer. But the object it points *to* is not made const by this, and can be modified. Which is not thread-safe. (Think of a smart pointer class, for a simple example. Or a const vector of non-const objects). But you're right about the C++11 change, which is the important part. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct synonym. Assume for example that you have a const pointer: it means that the adress itself is constant but not necessarily its content. So any function thatt would modify the content of this variable, when executed by several threads, is not considered to be thread-safe.