# Why modifiers like const not allowed on nonmember functions

Tags: c++, constants, volatile

I couldn't understand the reason for not allowing modifiers such as `const` or `volatile` to nonmembers functions.

Following is the example code I tired

```
class A
{
private:
    int var;
public:
    int func();
};

int A::func()
{
    // Some calculation on using var
    int temp = var + 10;
    return temp;
}

void func2( const A& tempObj ) const;

void func2( const A& tempObj ) 
{
    std::cout << "temp obj called : " << tempObj.func() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A aobj;
    aobj.func();
    func2( aobj );
    return 0;
}
```

which throws an compiler error `error C2270: 'func2' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions` for `void func2( const A& tempObj ) const;`

I also get another error `error C2662: 'A::func' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const A' to 'A &'` for `tempObj.func()` in `func2` here I was assuming that     the member function `func` will be called without any errors.

Comment: Also please help he understand `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const A' to 'A &'`. I think the conversion here is happening in other way round.

Comment: I dont see the volatile keyword in your example?

Comment: @S.C.Madsen yes I deliberately didn't used to make the question more generic.

Comment: Can you explain what you'd expect the modifier to mean?

Comment: @Angew please check the updated details in question

Comment: @Krishna_Oza That didn't answer the question.

Comment: The member function cannot be called for the same reason that you can't pass a const object to a function taking a reference to a non-const object.

Comment: I did check the updates, you just added another question, but didn't answer mine. What would you expect the meaning of a `const` qualifier on a non-member function to be?

Comment: @chris I guess here by using the `const_cast` for `tempObj` I would be able to call member function `func`. But I think the error message on VS2010 should have been other way around like `cannot convert form a cosnt & to const for object`.

Comment: @Angew I expected that the passed object is constant and when invoking a  member function on it would pass it as a constant object.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza That's the purpose of the `const` in `const A&`.

Comment: @downvoter: care to provide a reason for downvote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`const` modifier states that a member function won't modify data members of the object the function belongs to.

It's like an assurance that calling that function on an object `aobj` **won't modify the internal state of that object**. So, assuming that `aobj` is declared `const` too, you will still be able to invoke that function on it; on the contrary, you would not be able to invoke non `const` function members.

If a function is not member of a class, it makes no sense to apply `const` modifier. On another language, it could have meant that the function wasn't able to modify global variables, maybe; but that language is not C++.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine that there is a hidden parameter on each non-static member function:

```
int A::func(A* this) {...}
```

If you declare a member function const or volatile, that is added to that hidden parameter, pretty much like the following:

```
int A::func(const A* this) {...}
```

Some languages like python make the instance parameter on the member functions explicit, so there you write `def func(self):` inside a class definition to declare non-static functions.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the member function modifiers apply to the *object* on which the function is being called. That is the use the language has for these modifiers.

Non-member functions have no such object, so the qualification would make no sense. One could imagine the language allowing cv-qualifying non-members as having no effect, but in my mind this would only be confusing. One could also imagine the cv-qualifiers having a different meaning for non-members, but the reality is what it is. That is the way the language was designed.

Comment: still, `const` on non-members could mean something like "doesn't change global variables" or so, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: @davidhigh Right, but the answer to "Why modifiers like const not allowed on nonmember functions" is because the modifiers apply to the object, not to anything else.

Comment: @davidhigh, Realistically, that restriction would appear as part of "pure", which has been proposed and at least GCC has an attribute for.

Comment: @juanchopanza: sure, I was not criticizing your answer, but rather extending the question.

Comment: @davidhigh It is a good point though. In the end, it is a language design decision.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think the explanation for not allowing `const` to member function fairly answer my question but could you help me understand why with `const` removed from `func2` declaration I am getting error or unable to call `tempObj.func()` from `func2`.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza `A::func()` is not a `const` member function, so it can't be called via a `const` reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree to you and completely understand your point but isn't the error message `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const A' to 'A &` should be saying `cannot convert this pointer from const A& to const A`. Or since the `this` pointer itself is a `cosnt *`.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza No. The "this" pointer in your case is the `tempObj`, that is, a `const A`. But you're trying to call a non-`const` function on it, which requires an `A&` for its "this". So it's a conversion from `const A&` to `A&` which fails.

Answer (score 3):

A `const` qualification on a class method declares that the method doesn't modify any (non-mutable) member variables.

It therefore just doesn't make any sense to declare that on a non-member function because there are no member variables for it to modify.

The `const` qualification is very useful because it explicitly indicates that it's safe to call this method on a `const` variable without breaching the constness of that variable.