# Does thread-safe mean const in c++11/14?

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, constants

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11) asks if `const` means thread-safe, which Herb Sutter's [You don't know `const` and `mutable`](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) talk answers well. But what about the opposite direction? If a function is thread-safe, should it thereby be marked `const`? If not, when should a function be marked `const`?

Comment: You can easily construct a function that modifies state and is still thread-safe by providing appropriate synchronization mechanisms. It doesn't necessarily have to be `const`, unless I completely misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's perfectly possible for a method to be non `const` but still be thread safe.  Either it uses atomics, or a lock to protect member variables.  For example, the `count()` method below is thread safe, whilst modifying the `m_count` member variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

class Counter
{
public:
    Counter() : m_counterMutex(), m_counter(0) {}
    unsigned int count() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_counterMutex);
        ++m_counter;
        return m_counter;
    }
private:
    std::mutex m_counterMutex;
    unsigned int m_counter;

};
```

It shouldn't be marked as `const` because the visible state has changed.  It would surprise to users of the class that they could pass a `const Counter&` object to a function and the visible state of the object could be changed by that function.

Comment: This is where I ended up too. It seems the real lesson of the talk is "const things should be logically const and thread-safe", not just "const should be thread-safe"