# const_cast 'this' in const method to assign 'this' to outer variable?

Tags: c++

Have a look at the following code:

```
struct Foo;

Foo* bar;

struct Foo {
    void func() const {
        bar = this;
    }
}

int main() {
    Foo().func();
}
```

This does not work as `bar` won't accept a `const Foo*`. To get around this, `const_cast` could be used:

```
struct Foo {
    void func() const {
        bar = const_cast<Foo*>(this);
    }
}
```

Is this safe? I'm very cautious when it comes to using `const_cast`, but in this case it seems legit to me.

Comment: Why do you think it is not safe?
Also, why not just do `main() { bar = new Foo(); }`

Comment: Doesn't seem legit to me. The `this` pointer in `func()` is `const` saying "Here is a pointer to the object through which it should not be modifed". You've then assigned it to a pointer through which is may be modifed. Remove `const` from `func()` or add it to `bar` (`const Foo *bar;`).

Comment: Whatever the underlying reason for this, this is wrong. What is the real problem are you trying to solve. No, not the one that involves `const_cast`, but the problem to whose solution you think involves using `const_cast`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is potentially dangerous.

`func()` is marked `const` which means that it can be called by a const object:

```
const Foo foo;
foo.func();
```

Because `this` is `const Foo*`.

If you `const_cast` away the `const` you end up with a `Foo*` to a `const` object. This means that any modification to that object through the non-const pointer (or through any copy of that pointer, `bar` in this case) will get you undefined behavior since you are not allowed to modify a `const` object (duh).

Plus the obvious problem is that you're lying to the consumer of class `Foo` by saying `func()` won't modify anything while you're doing the opposite.

`const_cast` is almost never correct and this seems like an XY-problem to me.

Comment: "`const_cast` is almost never correct " : The obvious exception is something like `std::strch` which is overloaded to return a const pointer given a const argument, and non-const given a non-const argument.  One of the overloads will call the other with a const cast.

Comment: The other exception is where you have a crappy legacy API which has just forgotten to use `const`.  (But beware crappy legacy API's which actually modify the argument and then restore it - I'm looking at you [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx))

Answer (score 2):

If by "safe" you mean "not undefined behavior" then yes, it is safe. The value of `bar` will point to the created object as you'd expect.

However, `const_cast` is generally not recommended because it breaks the convention that a `const` thing will not be changed, and can easily produce undefined behavior (see [this comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837615/const-cast-this-in-const-method-to-assign-this-to-outer-variable/45837973#comment78646937_45837973)). In this case you can simply do:

```
struct Foo {
    void func() const {
        bar = const_cast<Foo*>(this);
        bar->modify();
    }
    void modify() { ... }
}
```

And you will be modifying the object in a `const` method, which is unexpected in general and undefined behavior if the instance of `Foo` on which the method is called was initially declared as `const`. However, it is up to you to get the logic right. Just note that everyone else will expect `const` things to be `const`, including the standard library, and usually (if not always) a better code design is possible.

Comment: It's not just a convention that const things will not be changed.  That call to `modify` is undefined behaviour.  (But you are correct that the assignment to bar is fine.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Really? I thought that was what `const_cast` is for (I don't think I've ever actually used in a real program, really), and only "highly dangerous", specially [since C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11), but not necessarily UB. Could you please point me to some explanation about that?

Comment: More precisely, it is UB if `func` is called on an object which was originally declared `const`.  So `Foo f; f.func();` is fine, but `const Foo f; f.func();` is UB.  See 7.1.6.1 para 4 in [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) "Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior."

Answer (score 0):

Under some circumstances it is safe, namely when you have a non-const `Foo` object. If you have a `const Foo` object however, you're not allowed to modify it, and the compiler will not catch the bug because of the cast. So it is not a good idea to use this.

Note that in your example `Foo` is a temporary which gets destroyed on the next line of `main()`.